# Legend format and placement using barplot in R

Tags: r

I would like to place the legend of my bar chart beneath the x axis and have it horizontally spread out landscape across the bottom of the chart if possible.

[image: As things stand my chart looks like this]

My data is as follows

```
dput(counts)

structure(c(11L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser. = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), g = c("1", "2")), class = "table")

counts
                                g
as.numeric.Final_DF.web_browser.  1  2
                               1 11 12
                               2  3  4
                               3  7  5
                               4  4  4
```

My code looks like

```
barplot(counts, names.arg=c("male", "female"),
        main = "Browser used during purchase",
        col = c("lightblue", "mistyrose", "lavender", "lightcoral"),
        ylab = "Count",
        beside = TRUE,
        legend.text = c("chrome", "internet explorer", "firefox", "netscape"),
        args.legend = list(x = 10, y = 10))
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: That can be done easily with `ggplot2`, would you consider an answer using that package?

Comment: Yes tried using it but got a bit stuck, any advice on how to use ggplot in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by adding the additional argument to `legend`: `horiz=T` and then adjusting the position.

```
barplot(counts, names.arg=c("male", "female"),
        main = "Browser used during purchase",
        col = c("lightblue", "mistyrose", "lavender", "lightcoral"),
        ylab = "Count",
        beside = TRUE,
        legend.text = c("chrome", "internet explorer", "firefox", "netscape"),
        args.legend = list(x = 9, y = -1.9, horiz=T))
```

[image: Repositioned legend]

Answer (score 1):

In `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
counts %>% as.data.frame.matrix %>%
  rownames_to_column('Var') %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var) %>%
  mutate(name=ifelse(name==1,'male','female'),
         name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Var),y=value,fill=Var))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("","","",""))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue", "mistyrose",
                             "lavender", "lightcoral"),
                    labels=c("chrome", "internet explorer",
                             "firefox", "netscape"))+
  facet_wrap(.~name,strip.position = 'bottom')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        axis.ticks.x =  element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  labs(x='')+
  ggtitle("Browser used during purchase")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks how to you change the y axis value? To counts? also remove Var from legend?

Comment: Just add `ylab('Counts')` and change `labs(fill='')`